# How to highlight the current scope with C family languages?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, parentheses, scope

While it's possible to highlight a block using the character under the cursor, is there a way to highlight the scope of the current cursor?

I'm interested in something like QtCreator's block-highlight feature: [image]

Are there existing packages that do this or should I make my own?

Answer (score 4):

A bit long in the tooth, but still seems to work fine, [highlight-sexp](https://github.com/daimrod/highlight-sexp) will do what you want. Move out of your inner `if`, it highlights the entire `for` block. Out again, the entire outer `if`. Out again, your function. Note that by default it highlights inside the "parens" of each scope.

[image: example of highlight-sexp's highlighting]

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor mode I've put together that highlights multiple enclosing brackets.

See: [hl-block-mode](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-hl-block-mode)

Since it's a relatively expensive operation, it's set to run after an idle timer - to avoid it slowing down cursor-motion.

[image]